# indexOf for strings not working after struts jquery plugin 3.7.1 upgrade

Tags: struts2-jquery

I upgraded struts jquery plugin to 3.7.1 and jquery-ui.js to 1.10.4.
With my previous struts jquery plugin 3.1.1 and jquery-ui.js  1.8.15, indexOf for the strings is working. Dont know where it hit after upgrade. I get the following error.

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'indexOf': object is null or undefined
```

My code is as below.

```
var innerSpanId = $(this).attr('id');
var value = innerSpanId.indexOf('accountcheckbox');
```

Do give in your suggestions?

Comment: With zero context it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to get the index of strings without an object.

In upgraded jquery use the string object.

```
var innerSpanId = new String($(this).attr('id'));
var value = innerSpanId.indexOf('accountcheckbox');
```

Works Perfect!!!